# Какой параметр Permission в Security Settings отвечает за возможность поставить галочку protect container from accidental deletion?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, windows-server

В Active Directory есть OU, и есть пользователь, который должен внутри создавать внутри этой OU новые OU.
Вопрос в следующем: какие permissions надо дать пользователю, чтобы он мог при создании новой OU ставить галочку protect container from accidental deletion? По умолчанию она серая неактивная.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]